# .cshtml File Not Refreshing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a file named _RelatedProductsPartial.cshtml located in an MVC project in the Views/Shared folder that is used as a partial view inside a products page to render a carousel of potentially related products. The related products show up as expected, but the URLs are incorrect. I made a backup of the file and tried editing the file to fix how the URLs are being dynamically generated and saved the file and tried again, but my changes were not reflected as the URLs are still in the original format. I even tried just editing some text and retesting and that change was not reflected either. My question is, do parital/Shared views actually need to be compiled into the relevant DLL? Is that why I am not seeing the changes reflected? I am new to Asp.net so I hope there is a simple solution to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: From where does those url's coming , database or statically?

Comment: @Dhiren the URLs for the related products are dynamically generated using string concatenation based on a productType and productSerial variable that comes from the DB. The issue is the concatenation puts them in the wrong format so I replaced that with a String.format() function to put them in the correct format but the changes are not reflected when I save the .cshtml file and try and reload a product to see the updated links to related products.

Comment: Do you have a minimal code example?

Comment: The code is on a closed network but here is how it is currently creating the URL: @Url.Action("Display", new {controller = p.ProductTypeFileLocation, product = p.ProductSerialNumber}). That is how the URL is currently dynamically generated and that results in something like Display?product=ABC-0001-2018 but the URL should  actually be Products/ABC/ABC-0001-2018 and I used the String.format() function to put the URL in the correct format but the changes are not reflected when I save the .cshtml file on the server and try and test it.

Comment: try to clean the code and clear all files and folders from %temp% location and again build the whole project

Comment: I edited the relevant file directly on the server. Are you saying I probably need to rebuild the whole project to get the change to the .cshtml file to take effect? @Dhiren

Comment: no need to rebuild but what is ABC in Products/ABC/...

Comment: @Dhiren ABC is the product type and ABC-0001-2018 is the actual serial of the product so product ABC-0001-2018 would be stored in a folder named ABC. Any idea why these changes are not being reflected? Should I be able to edit a .cshtml file directly on the server and see the changes reflected? In our test environment I edited the index.cshtml (home page) file just to add a few characters  of text and that change was reflected so I have no idea why I can't see the changes to the file located at Views/Shared/_RelatedProductsPartial.cshtml  on our production server.

Comment: try making some changes in plain html elements or code and check if changes rendered in production server.

Comment: @Dhiren I had already tried that and just tried that again, changes are not reflected.

Comment: strange issue otherwise whatever changes it reflects easily in cshtml as it afterall html page only with server values. Hope you cross checked everything i.e. file path, file name, create static anchor tags and check in procution server,  try render anchor string.format in @Html.Raw() if it helps.